# Extract digit in a string

Tags: c#

I have a list of string

```
goal0=1234.4334abc12423423
goal1=-234234
asdfsdf
```

I want to extract the number part from string that start with goal, 
in the above case is

```
1234.4334, -234234
```

(if two fragments of digit get the first one)
 how should i do it easily?

Note that "goal0=" is part of the string, goal0 is not a variable.
Therefore I would like to have the first digit fragment that come after "=".

Comment: Did you check this? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcw2f1c.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
string s = "goal0=-1234.4334abc12423423";
string matches =  Regex.Match(s, @"(?<=^goal\d+=)-?\d+(\.\d+)?").Value;
```

The regex says

- `(?<=^goal\d+=)` - A positive look behind which means look back and make sure `goal(1 or more number)=` is at the start of the string, but dont make it part of the match
- `-?` - A minus sign which is optional (the `?` means 1 or more)
- `\d+` - One or more digits
- `(\.\d+)?` - A decimal point followed by 1 or more digits which is optional

This will work if your string contains multiple decimal points as well as it will only take the first set of numbers after the first decimal point if there are any.

Comment: Slightly updated regex as didn't notice questions said "start with goal" rather than "contains goal"

Answer (score 4):

You can do the following:

```
        string input = "goal0=1234.4334abc12423423";
        input = input.Substring(input.IndexOf('=') + 1);

        IEnumerable<char> stringQuery2 = input.TakeWhile(c => Char.IsDigit(c) || c=='.' || c=='-');
        string result = string.Empty;
        foreach (char c in stringQuery2)
            result += c;
        double dResult = double.Parse(result);
```

Comment: if the text is `goal1=1234.1234.1234avbd`this will try to convert the `1234.1234.1234`to double which will fail

Comment: @Tobsey I don't know if he wants to convert it to double or not. I have understood that there is a number before characters. In that case the code is OK. I can remove the parsing, it was for his convenience only

Comment: @Nick I think what Tobsey means is if the string has 2 decimal points in (not given as an example in original question), the code will continue to take until it hits a letter and then try and convert `"1234.1234.1234"` to a double/what ever

Comment: @didster Yes I understand that, from the question, but he said he is expecting number before characters. If it is the number, it won't have many dots.

Answer (score 2):

Use a regex for extracting:

```
x = Regex.Match(string, @"\d+").Value;
```

Now convert the resulting string to the number by using:

```
finalNumber = Int32.Parse(x);
```

Comment: That will not work.  If `string="goal0=1234.4334abc12423423"` then that regex would match the first digit, 0.

Answer (score 2):

Please try this:

```
string sample = "goal0=1234.4334abc12423423goal1=-234234asdfsdf";

Regex test = new Regex(@"(?<=\=)\-?\d*(\.\d*)?", RegexOptions.Singleline);
MatchCollection matchlist = test.Matches(sample);

string[] result = new string[matchlist.Count];
if (matchlist.Count > 0)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < matchlist.Count; i++)
    result[i] = matchlist[i].Value;
}
```

Hope it helps.

I didn't get the question at first. Sorry, but it works now.

Comment: All the regex statements that only extract digits will stop when it reaches letters and not retrieve the digits after. This solution works.

Comment: @JTC if `sample` = what is said in the question (`"goal0=-1234.4334abc12423423"`) it doesnt work.  `_result` would = `"0=-1234.433412423423"`

Comment: @didster sorry at first I didn't get the question, please check my edited answer. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think this simple expression should work:

```
Regex.Match(string, @"\d+")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the old VB `Val()` function from C#. That will extract a number from the front of a string, and it's already available in the framework:

```
result0 = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Conversion.Val(goal0);
result1 = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Conversion.Val(goal1);
```

Comment: I can't find the class Microsoft.VisualBasic.Conversion, but can find Microsoft.VisualBasic, am using VS 2010

Comment: Documentation on the method is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9da280t0(v=vs.100).aspx. You may need to add a reference to Microsoft.VisualBasis in your project.

Answer (score 0):

```
string s = "1234.4334abc12423423";
var result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(s, @"-?\d+");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<String> list = new List<String>();

list.Add("goal0=1234.4334abc12423423");
list.Add("goal1=-23423");
list.Add("asdfsdf");

Regex regex = new Regex(@"^goal\d+=(?<GoalNumber>-?\d+\.?\d+)");

foreach (string s in list)
{
    if(regex.IsMatch(s))
    {
        string numberPart = regex.Match(s).Groups["GoalNumber"];

        // do something with numberPart
    }
}
```